# Lethal force to defend killer dogs?

Tags: united-states, self-defense, animals

Let's consider the following scenario, taking place in an American state where self defense in defense of property and castle laws are in effect.

An intruder onto a man's property is mauled to death by his dogs. The man promptly lodges an application for an emergency injunction against the local/state animal control services, seeking to prohibit the confiscation and destruction of his dogs.

Prior to this application being heard by a judge, an animal control officer arrives at the property and is then shot dead. During the ensuing police standoff, the man declares that he was acting in self defence, that he will peacefully surrender if the emergency injunction he applied for is approved and a copy of the approval is delivered to him by his lawyer, and that he is willing to die fighting to protect his dogs. In the interests of preventing unnecessary bloodshed, the judge approves the injunction, and the man does surrender peacefully.

At the resulting trial, he advances the following arguments:

1. Any intruder on his property has unknown intentions, and must be assumed to be there to murder him and his family. If he had been present, the initial intruder would have been shot dead by the man, and it would have been self-defense. As such, the intruder being killed by his dogs was self-defense - the dogs were simply the weapon he used to defend the lives of his family, no different than an autonomous killer drone.
2. The dogs should not be destroyed because they were acting in accordance with their training to defend the property from intruders, and once you cross the property line, you have forfeited your right to continue living - and they pose no additional danger to the community beyond that he himself does.
3. The animal control officer was there to kill his dogs. His dogs were members of his family, and he was acting in self-defense to protect the lives of his family.
4. Even if that argument doesn't fly, he was still acting to defend his property (his dogs), so it was still self-defense.
5. Once the threat to the lives of members of his family (and/or property) was averted, he peacefully surrendered.

What would likely result at trial? Would he be able to successfully argue self-defense? Would he be able to save the life of his dogs?

Comment: "an animal control officer arrives at the property and is then shot dead." as written, this is murder. Unless the officer used or threaten to use force. Did they bring a gun to shot the dogs on the spot? Did they try to subdue the owner or hold them at gunpoint and take the dogs by force?

Comment: Is an autonomous killer drone a lawful self-defence weapon in this scenario?

Comment: I have a hard time imagining *anything* that is not able of informed choice to be a valid self defense weapon. After all, they would need to stop their "self defense" when a valid court order is presented and I doubt a drone or dog could do that. But then, it is the US and I am not a lawyer... lots of things that seem crazy in other parts of the world might be legal there.

Comment: "once you cross the property line, you have forfeited your right to continue living" is an interesting statement.

Comment: @WeatherVane Anything that crosses the property line is a potentially lethal threat (you don't know if they have a gun on them or what their intentions are), therefore you are justified to use lethal force to take them down (at least in castle doctrine states).

Comment: Does your postman deliver the mail?

Comment: @gnasher729 Does the postman need to enter the property proper to do so? There's usually a letterbox and a clear path to the front door for parcels. No need to jump the fence.

Comment: What did "the man" do with the two dead humans? String 'em up as warnings?

Comment: I’m actually not sure what the significance of the dog is here. Do you suppose you’re allowed to kill someone who’s there to arrest you, if you’re facing the death penalty?

Comment: "therefore you are justified to use lethal force to take them down (at least in castle doctrine states)" No, you are not. You are not allowed to kill anybody, just because they tipped their toe on your property. Please do some prior research and at least read a wikipedia article about or something.

Comment: @nvoigt You are, though? Self-defense just needs you to consider them a reasonable threat to your life to kill them - and everyone who trespasses is a reasonable threat to your life, since you don't know what their intentions are. Maybe they want to steal your TV. Maybe they want to murder you and rape your wife. You have no way of telling, so you're justified in killing them either way.

Comment: No. I cannot fathom how you think you are allowed to kill random strangers because they enter your property. "reasonable threat" is not mere presence and your paranoia. Yes, a stranger in the night sneaking around armed, I can see that. But you cannot just torch the neighbours girl with a flamethrower because she wanted to recover her ball from your yard in broad daylight. Get real man. "reasonable threat" means a *reasonable threat*. Lawyeresque is hard to decipher, but your reading does not even hold up to the plain english meaning of the words.

Comment: Which trial are you talking about? The (alleged) murder of the intruder, the murder of the animal control officer, or the one for blackmailing the judge?

Comment: Does this state have [Breed Specific Legislation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breed-specific_legislation)?

Comment: The mail persons, delivery drivers and neighborhood kids enter our property all the time. They do not "forfeit their lives" by doing so and we generally don't shoot them. If the legal situation where otherwise, Amazon would NOT deliver in castle states.

Comment: @Hilmar "The mail persons, delivery drivers and neighborhood kids enter our property all the time." The first two *don't* enter the property proper - the private areas of the property, like the backyard or the interior of the house. The last ones might, but if they do, again, see before about not knowing their intentions or whether or not they're armed. Juvenile delinquents are just as much of a threat as adults.

Comment: @Rick Presume that the dogs aren't a restricted breed if there is.

Answer (score 4):

1. That is not a valid assumption. Many states have laws that let you presume someone is a threat to your life if they *forcibly* enter your *house*. Simple trespass on your land does not let you reasonably presume someone is a murderer. An autonomous killer drone is not a comparison you want to make: those may be illegal entirely, and are likely to seriously hurt any claim of justifiable force.
2. “You forfeit your right to live when you set foot on my property” is not justifiable. If the dogs are trained to be a hazard to the community, that’s an argument *in favor* of having them confiscated and destroyed.
3. Dogs are not people. Under normal circumstances, they cannot be protected under self-defense or the defense of others. Those doctrines only apply when a *person* is in danger.
4. Deadly force is sometimes allowed to protect property, but this tends to be strictly limited. To start with, you can only ever use force to prevent *illegal* damage to property. If your concern is “this animal control officer will destroy my dogs within the scope of their duty,” that’s not protecting against an illegal use of force. Deadly force in defense of property is also normally limited to particular crimes that are inherently dangerous, like arson, robbery, or burglary. Even in Texas, simple theft only justifies deadly force during the nighttime. Deadly force is also not justifiable if there were reasonable other options. Shooting an animal control officer is unlikely to be the only way to temporarily stop them from destroying a dog.
5. Threatening violence in order to influence a judge’s decision is *terrorism*. This hypothetical man is a terrorist. He may well find himself on death row for murder, but he’s also going to face separate charges for terrorism.